# Cluster X, Y values into Sector and Plot in pandas, pandas groupby and or scikit

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
X    Y     Sector     Plot
5    3     SE1        P2
3    3     SE1        P1
6    7     SE1        P3
1    6     SE1        P3
2    1     SE1        P1
7    3     SE1        P2
17   20    SE2        P1
23   22    SE2        P1
27   28    SE2        P3
31   25    SE2        P3
25   25    SE2        P2
31   31    SE2        P2
17   25    SE2        P4
23   31    SE2        P4
```

From the above data, I would like to estimate the min and max values of X and Y for each Sector, Plot combination.

The expected output of the data frame as shown below.

```
Sector_Plot  Xmin  Xmax  Ymin  Ymax
SE1_P1       2     3     1     3
SE1_P2       5     7     3     3
SE1_P3       1     6     6     7
SE2_P1       17    23    20    22
SE2_P2       25    31    25    25
SE2_P3       27    31    25    31
SE2_P4       17    23    25    31
```

From the above rule if we get new X, Y we should be able to Predict Sector_Plot as shown below.

```
X    Y    Estimated_Sector_Plot
2.5  2    SE1_P1
2    1    SE1_P1
3    2    SE1_P1
5    3    SE1_P2
7    3    SE1_P2
6    3    SE1_P2
1    7    SE1_P3
4    6    SE1_P3
2    7    SE1_P3
28   25   SE2_P3
29   31   SE2_P3
18   19   SE2_P1
17   20   SE2_P1
19   22   SE2_P1
30   25   SE2_P2
25   25   SE2_P2
18   26   SE2_P4
17   31   SE2_P4
```

I tried machine learning method it was a flop. Is that can be done by any other methods?

I am sharing my code below

```
def find_frequent_labels(df, var, rare_perc):
    df = df.copy()
    tmp = df.groupby(var)['X'].count() / len(df)
    return tmp[tmp>rare_perc].index    
for var in ['SECTOR']:
    frequent_ls = find_frequent_labels(train, var, 0.01)
    train[var] = np.where(train[var].isin(frequent_ls), train[var], 'Rare')
    test[var] = np.where(test[var].isin(frequent_ls), test[var], 'Rare')    
def replace_with_X(train1, test1, var, target):
    ordered_labels = train1.groupby([var])[target].mean().sort_values().index
    ordinal_label = {k:i for i, k in enumerate(ordered_labels, 0)} 
    train1['Sec_X'] = train1[var].map(ordinal_label)
    test1['Sec_X'] = test1[var].map(ordinal_label)    
for var in ['SECTOR']:
    replace_with_X(train, test, var, 'X')    
def replace_with_Y(train1, test1, var, target):
    ordered_labels = train1.groupby([var])[target].mean().sort_values().index
    ordinal_label = {k:i for i, k in enumerate(ordered_labels, 0)} 
    train1['Sec_Y'] = train1[var].map(ordinal_label)
    test1['Sec_Y'] = test1[var].map(ordinal_label)    
for var in ['SECTOR']:
    replace_with_Y(train, test, var, 'Y')    
train['Plot_id'] = train['PLOT'].factorize()[0]
category_id_df = train[['PLOT', 'Plot_id']].drop_duplicates().sort_values('Plot_id')
category_to_id = dict(category_id_df.values)
id_to_category = dict(category_id_df[['Plot_id', 'PLOT']].values)
category_to_id = dict(category_id_df.values)
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
model = LinearSVC(C=1.0, class_weight='balanced')
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, indices_train, indices_test = train_test_split(train[['X', 'Y', 'Sector_code']], train['Plot_id'], train.index, test_size=0.01, random_state=0)    
model.fit(X_train, y_train)    
test['Plot_id'] = model.predict(test[['X', 'Y', 'Sector_code']])
```

Please note that I am very new in machine leaning and pandas

Comment: `df.groupby(['Sector', 'Plot']).agg(['min', 'max'])` to get your first result

Comment: @user3483203 is above one can be done by any other methods? If I get  advice from experts I can leave this question and try learning something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of task can be solved with [vector quantization](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.vq.html). Instead of min and max we need the centroids (mean x/y coordinates) of each sector_plot cluster. Then we get the nearest cluster with [`scipy.cluster.vq.vq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.vq.html#scipy-cluster-vq-vq):

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.cluster.vq import vq

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [ 5,  3,  6,  1,  2,  7, 17, 23, 27, 31, 25, 31, 17, 23],
                   'Y': [ 3,  3,  7,  6,  1,  3, 20, 22, 28, 25, 25, 31, 25, 31],
                   'Sector': ['SE1', 'SE1', 'SE1', 'SE1', 'SE1', 'SE1', 'SE2', 'SE2', 'SE2', 'SE2', 'SE2', 'SE2', 'SE2', 'SE2'],
                   'Plot': ['P2', 'P1', 'P3', 'P3', 'P1', 'P2', 'P1', 'P1', 'P3', 'P3', 'P2', 'P2', 'P4', 'P4']})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X': [ 2.5,  2 ,  3 ,  5 ,  7 ,  6 ,  1 ,  4 ,  2 , 28 , 29 , 18 , 17 , 19 , 30 , 25 , 18 , 17 ],
                   'Y': [ 2,  1,  2,  3,  3,  3,  7,  6,  7, 25, 31, 19, 20, 22, 25, 25, 26, 31]})

# prepare given dataframe, get centroids (means)
df['Sector_Plot'] = df.Sector + '_' + df.Plot
df = df.drop(['Sector', 'Plot'],1)
df = df.groupby(['Sector_Plot']).agg(['min', 'max', 'mean']).reset_index()
df.columns = [''.join(col) for col in df.columns]

# find nearest sector_plot for each entry in the other dataframe
res = vq(df1.values, df[['Xmean','Ymean']].values)
df1['Estimated_Sector_Plot'] = df.iloc[res[0]].Sector_Plot.values
```

Result:

```
       X   Y Estimated_Sector_Plot
0    2.5   2                SE1_P1
1    2.0   1                SE1_P1
2    3.0   2                SE1_P1
3    5.0   3                SE1_P2
4    7.0   3                SE1_P2
5    6.0   3                SE1_P2
6    1.0   7                SE1_P3
7    4.0   6                SE1_P3
8    2.0   7                SE1_P3
9   28.0  25                SE2_P3
10  29.0  31                SE2_P2
11  18.0  19                SE2_P1
12  17.0  20                SE2_P1
13  19.0  22                SE2_P1
14  30.0  25                SE2_P3
15  25.0  25                SE2_P2
16  18.0  26                SE2_P4
17  17.0  31                SE2_P4
```